# Define default type and default required for VUE props

Tags: vue.js

The properties of one of my Vue components are all required and type Array.

```
    props: {
        completed: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        remaining: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        todos: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    }
```

There are only three props, but If there were more I'd have to repeat the code for all of them.
Is there a way to set all props to be required and type Array?

```
props: {
     // the following code should be equivalent to the previous one
     completed, remaining, todos: {
          required: true,
          type: Array
     }
}
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work because this is not how JS objects work.

The best I came up with was this:

```
    // at the beginning of the code
    let params = {type: Array, required:true};

    // ...
    // in the object
    props: {
        completed: params,
        remaining: params,
        todos: params
    }
```

Any way to make it more efficient? I'm just looking for a shortcut, since I often discover that there are ways to make code cleaner and more efficient that I didn't know until I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should not do this but here is how you can achieve it through [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const component = {
  props: {
     ...['completed', 'remaining', 'todos'].reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = {              
          required: true,
          type: Array
        }, obj), {}),
  }
}

console.log(component)
```

Also check out:

- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

---

You can create a helper function as well:

```js
const component = {
  props: {
    ...myProps(['completed', 'remaining', 'todos'], Array, true)
  },
}

console.log(component)


function myProps(arr, type, required) {
  return arr.reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = { required, type }, obj), {})
}
```

Comment: That's a very clever solution. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you say I should not do this?

Comment: Mainly because of maintainability and readability reasons. Unless you're gonna have tens of props. Actually you can wrap it in a helper function something like this: `myProps(['a', 'b'], /* type */Array, /* required */ true)`

Comment: @StudentofSciences I updated the answer to include what I mean